# CPUERR light after stress test and failure to POST. Is this definitely a CPU failure?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, post, stress-test

I have a high-value CPU (XEON E5-2698 v3) CPU that has failed a stress test (I believe). The ASUS Z10PE motherboard is lighting the CPUERR_LED3 light, the system fails to boot, stopping at Q-code 04 "PCH inisialising before microcode loading".

When swapping/isolating the pair of CPUs, this unit seems to be the failure point. Under what circumstances can a CPU fail, or was this a faulty part? Will a CPU allow itself to overheat or will safeties generally keep it protected? I can see CPU temperature was maintained to sub 60 degC for the test, at least as far as the log got.

Comment: The CPU is 4-5 years old. Generally CPUs try to stay within their thermal budget but there are quite a few influencing factors. Which temperature (which sensor) did you log?

Comment: Main temp (not the cores).

Comment: It is a dual CPU machine with two identical units like this one. I checked the reported CPU temperature for each, not the individual cores.